# Error 2042 in Vlookup VBA despite type and value equality

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

Summerization: Despite seeming equality of two strings, they do not match match the text in their respective cells. Even though the third one does match with its.

I was given task "if possible" to simplify navigating through a complex excel WorkBook. I figured out a better way to generate IDs, as the old ones are almost nonsensical.

My IDs are created from 3 different numbers and the macro I'm making reverses these IDs with description explaining what the ID stands for.

Example: 550000210 first five stand for the account, the two after for the purpose and last two for the distribution (method). All 3 IDs are of the same format (or so I think so) and they are all strings(text). The final ID is a string(text), too.

To me surprise, however, it is not easy to use VLookup function in VBA and besides the first 5 digits, the two pairs don't match with the values in the ranges they refer too.

That made me think the named ranges within the "legenda" sheet do not share format, as the account number is generated by an online system but the pairs are by me. So I removed the formating and copied the format of the account numbers and it didn't change anything, tried double instead didn't help.
 Using add watch, it says number I expect it to find is the same type "Variant/String", when I make an if condition where i compare them, it goes through successfully.

I'm really getting desperate, I do not necessarily have a time pressure but this was supposed to be a minor step to a "try" attempt to see if it goes anywhere for the task.

```
Let sel = Selection.Value 'user selects the code they want (vbModeless)
Let a = Left(sel, 5) 'first 5 digits
Let b = Mid(sel, 6, 2) 'the two after
Let c = Right(sel, 2) 'left two digits

Label1.Caption = a
Label2.Caption = b
Label3.Caption = c

Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
Set targetWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook
Set legendaSheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets("legenda")

Dim ra As Range, rb As Range, rc As Range

Set ra = legendaSheet.Range("account")
Set rb = legendaSheet.Range("purpose")
Set rc = legendaSheet.Range("distribution")

'changes single digit back to single digit (needed)
'code does not work even when this condition isn't needed (aka numbers 10 or higher)
If Left(b, 1) = "0" Then
    b = Replace(b, "0", "")
End If

If Left(c, 1) = "0" Then
    c = Replace(c, "0", "")
End If


Let e = Application.VLookup(a, ra, 2, False) 'works here
Let f = Application.VLookup(b, rb, 1, False) 'error 2042
Let g = Application.VLookup(c, rc, 1, False) 'error 2042

Label4.Caption = e
Label5.Caption = f
Label6.Caption = g
```

Expected result is having the part of ID in left column of labels and description in the right one. It works only for "a". I suspect the issue really still is formating however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 2042 is returned when VLOOKUP does not find the value. It would be #N/A if VLOOKUP was used in a formula (entered into a cell).

First of all, make sure that the data types match. Your variables a, b, and c are of type String, which stores text data. Most probably rb and rc contain numbers instead of text. So you have to convert b (and c) to a numeric value:

```
Let f = Application.VLookup(CLng(b), rb, 1, False) 'error 2042
```

Second, you should prepare your code for the case when no value is found:

```
Let f = "not found"
On Error Resume Next
f = Application.VLookup(CLng(b), rb, 1, False) 'error 2042
On Error Goto 0
' If found, f is the value from the sheet, otherwise "not found"
```

Alternatively, you may convert the data on the sheet to the correct type.

**Update**

OK, so the problem was that you want to search in the second column of purpose. To do this, you have to adjust that rb:

```
Set rb = legendaSheet.Range("purpose").Offset(0, 1)
```

If the column you want to return from the row found is before the one you search in, then you will have to use the INDEX and MATCH functions.

Comment: Hello, the numbers within the ranges are in text format, as mentioned I copied the format from the working range (rc). For example: If I type "01" instead of "1" in a cell within ra and/or rb ranges, it remains so "01" instead of rearrenging back to "1".

Comment: Can you stop your code in the debugger when it encounters the error?

Comment: I might have an idea, however it is a bit brute strenght. Maybe I should just take both the (b or c) values and rb and rc ranges' respective column and just convert them to the same format within the VBA just for the use within the vlookup

Comment: Yes, I can, it does not crash the macro. f g just become error type and don't return anything into the labels. 
Edit. Actually the code stops  working when it tries to put the error into labels' captions

Comment: Then stop it there, and print the value and type in the Immediate Window: `? b, TypeName(b), rb.Cells(1,1).Value, TypeName(rb.Cells(1,1).Value)` and see if they match.

Comment: If they match, then note the value of b, and try to locate it on the sheet. Also check that it is inside your named range (purpose) by hitting Ctrl+F3

Comment: ? b, TypeName(b), rb.Cells(1,1).Value, TypeName(rb.Cells(1,1).Value)
7             String        Účel          String

Comment: ? b, TypeName(b), rb.Cells(8,2).Value, TypeName(rb.Cells(8,2).Value)
7             String        7             String

Comment: Vlookup searches in the first column, so it won’t find it in cells(8,2)

Comment: Oh, you are right I completely forgot about that, well then that's most likely the issue, a dumb mistake on my part. Is there a way to make it still work. I can not swap the columns within the excel sheets because other vlookup functions work with them. But I should be able to do it within VBA just for the ranges, correct? Or just make new tables with swapped columns.

Thanks a lot, I thought about it, since the "a" part is in the first column but I just scrapped that, now when you told me I remember, thank you a lot for your time and I'm sorry to waste it.